# What are the best practices in quality assurance process measurement?

Tags: tools, metrics

How do you measure quality assurance and quality of products in your teams? What metrics do you use? What tools do you use?

Comment: I think a more specific question would help here (or a rephrase so it seemed specific enough for me to answer). Metrics is a huge area, and there are a million ways to measure the moving target of quality.

Comment: Agreed - its like asking "please list all possible good answers to questions in this forum".  *grin*

Comment: Agreed. Please specify a concrete question.

Comment: wonder if there are any best practices which fit all the shops

Comment: I agree this is too broad.

Comment: @user45: This is too broad for a Q&A site about "quality assurance". These sites work better when you have a very specific question you come across in your everyday work.

Answer (score 4):

There are no "best" practices in my opinion.
As others on the internet stated before, there might be "good" or "good enough" practices.

But.

You have to see it in context.
One good practice which fits perfectly for your company, product, people, etc.. (~context), might be TOTALLY wrong in my company, product, people, etc. :-)

Also on the note of "metrics".
This can be a dangerous thing as well. Often you get, what you measure.

If I would be evaluated/paid by the amount of bugs, you can bet, that I would find dozens every day (or what ever the needed amount is).

If this would be "real" bugs or not.. wouldn't matter much for me (if my pay depends on it).

Also for developers: If you measure them by lines of code, you can bet you get dozens of lines, even when the function could be neatly fit in one line.

:-)